# How to read values from NSArray of NSDictionaries

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have an array of NSDictionary values that looks like this when NSLogged

```
{
 HASMOD = F;
 ISLOCKED = F;
 ISREGD = F;
 MANU = "HORNET";
 ID = 706;
},
 {
 HASMOD = T;
 ISLOCKED = F;
 ISREGD = T;
 MANU = "BANJI";
 ID = 225;
},
//etc
```

I am trying to save these values to my core data object (with correct types). I have been following this [tutorial](http://goo.gl/wF5h1) and have reached the point where I am trying to insert the values into each of the objects, However I am not sure how to do this from an array of dictionaries.. as it only shows how to enter one lot of information

So I have attempted doing it myself.. but its more pseudo code than anything... this is as far I have as I done... hopefully it helps make sense of what I am trying to achieve.

```
// WRITE TO CORE DATA
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    Manuf *manuf = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Manuf" inManagedObjectContext:context];


    int mycount = [parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries count];

    while (mycount != 0) {

        // Somehow read Dictionaries and put them into their correct value types
        BOOL hasModBool;
        hasModelBool =

        BOOL isLockedBool;
        isLockedBool =

        BOOL isRegedBool;
        isRegedBool =

        NSString *manuString = [[NSString alloc] init];
        manuString =

        int manuIDInt;
        manuIDInt =


        // pass all the values into the manuf coredata obj
        manuf.hasMod = hasModBool;
        manuf.isLocked = isLockedBool;
        manuf.isReged = isRegedBool;
        manuf.manu = manuString;
        manuf.manuID = manuIDInt;

        count --; // itterate through the array
    }
```

I am hoping someone can help me run through the array of dictionaries and insert them into the variables of my core data object..

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a for-in loop to iterate through your array, and get the values with valueForKey:.

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries) {
     Manuf *manuf = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Manuf" inManagedObjectContext:context];
     BOOL hasModelBool;
     BOOL isLockedBool;
     BOOL isRegedBool;
     if([dict valueForKey:@"HASMOD"] isEqualToString:@"T"]) {
        hasModelBool = TRUE;
     }else{
        hasModelBool = FALSE;
     if([dict valueForKey:@"ISLOCKED"] isEqualToString:@"T"]) {
        isLockedBool = TRUE;
     }else{
        isLockedBool = FALSE;
     ......
     ......
     // pass all the values into the manuf coredata obj
    manuf.hasMod = hasModBool;
    manuf.isLocked = isLockedBool;
    manuf.isReged = isRegedBool;
    manuf.manu = manuString;
    manuf.manuID = manuIDInt;
}
```

I'm assuming here that the "T" or "F" values in your dictionaries are strings that need to be converted to TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: okay cool trying out your solution now :) also yes they are to be converted was going to look into how to do this after I figure out how to just get the values :P but I see you have done this for me! thank you very much!

Comment: okay so been trying a few things to  resolve this warning and error but cannot figure it out.. on